# How to remove systemd's service in yocto?

Tags: service, yocto, systemd

I want to delete unnecessary *systemd* services. I tried a few method in my custom layer, but nothing is working. Is there another way?

1. ```
   layer.conf
   PACKAGECONFIG_remove_pn-systemd = " timesyncd connman nfs-server bluetooth psplash-basic atd"
   ```
2. ```
   recipes-core/systemd/systemd_%.bbappend
   PACKAGECONFIG_remove = "timesyncd connman nfs-server bluetooth psplash-basic atd"
   ```

Comment: I think you can probably directly remove the concerned package from your image can't you ?

Comment: @YCN I could do that, but I wanted to use the build system.

Comment: systemd services are created by `inherit systemd` and `SYSTEMD_SERVICE` variable, so you should try in systemd_%.bbappend `SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN}-xyz_remove = " ...."`. Another option is to only disable service autostart with `SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE` variable

Comment: You also shouldn't use layer.conf but local.conf instead (or create your own distribution configuration).

Comment: @Nayfe, that's what i wanted!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, these packageconfigs aren't in systemd recipe, you can only remove packageconfig that are in this list [systemd_239.bb](https://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_239.bb#n129)

Comment: I seem to know something wrong.
I just want to delete unnecessary services.

Answer (score 0):

'bitbake -e systemd' should tell you the final value of PACKAGECONFIG, and how it was formed.

Answer (score 0):

1:
Change

```
#PACKAGECONFIG[networkd] = "-Dnetworkd=true,-Dnetworkd=false"
```

To

```
PACKAGECONFIG[networkd] = "-Dnetworkd=false,-Dnetworkd=true"
```

please refer to [systemd_253.1](https://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_253.1.bb)

I removed networkd from systemd but not audit, so you need to test:

2: werther can be built by "bitbake systemd "

3:bitbake imx-image-core(or full) if above be passed and then find folder or run cmd to test services whether exist.

Comment: I edited your post to be more clear, that is if I correctly understood the answer. If I didn’t, please edit or roll back the edit.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.